# Facebook Box Count Like Button Vertical Alignment Change

Tags: html, css, facebook, alignment

[image]

I'm using this kind of button. How to align this box count value to the right of Facebook Like label. Like the below twitter format

[image]

**I am used the below HTML:**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

**Scirpt:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `button_count` instead of `box_count`. All possible options are selectable in the button generator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: that is not possible, you can only use the options from the button generator and you are not allowed to change the appearance in any way - except for using the options.